# Split a string on alternating index

Tags: r, string, split

I have a string similar to `"HLeelmloon"` which is two words interweaved together. How can I separate this into two separate words, splitting on alternating letters?

I can use `strsplit()` and a `for` loop to allocate alternating letters to two new vectors and then join the list but this seems very long winded:

```
string <- "HLeelmloon"
split<-el(strsplit(string,''))

> split
[1] "H" "L" "e" "e" "l" "m" "l" "o" "o" "n"

word1<-c()
word2<-c()
for(i in 1:length(split)){
  if(i %% 2 == 1){
    word1<-append(word1, split[i])
  } else {
    word2<-append(word2, split[i])
  }
}

word1 = paste0(word1, collapse = '')
word2 = paste0(word2, collapse = '')

> word1
[1] "Hello"
> word2
[1] "Lemon"
```

My issue is it's not very elegant, and it doesn't upscale well if I want to split the string into N different words. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "N different words" - can you give example? Also, do words always have the same number of letters?

Comment: Being able to say N=3, and split a string "abc" into "a", "b", and "c"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `gsub` to capture alternating characters into the same group:

```
gsub("(.)(.)?", "\\1", string)
#[1] "Hello"
gsub("(.)(.)?", "\\2", string)
#[1] "Lemon"
```

Comment: This can also be expanded to multiple words by using extra `(.)` such as: `gsub("(.)(.)(.)?", "\\3", "abcabc")` returns `cc`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using `TRUE` and `FALSE` for indexing, i.e.

```
v1 = strsplit(string, '')[[1]]

paste(v1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], collapse = '')
#[1] "Hello"

paste(v1[c(FALSE, TRUE)], collapse = '')
#[1] "Lemon"
```

Comment: This was exactly the trick I was looking for, but chose @Mike H.'s answer as it scales up to more than 2 words

Answer (score 2):

Considering your question is how to split into more than two words, you should use the `split` function. Using your example data can be a bit confusing because you chose to name one variable 'split'. In the following block, the first 'split' is the function, the second one your split variable.

```
number_of_words <- 2
lapply(split(split,1:number_of_words),paste0,collapse='')

$`1`
[1] "Hello"

$`2`
[1] "Lemon"

number_of_words <- 3
lapply(split(split,1:number_of_words),paste0,collapse='')
$`1`
[1] "Heln"

$`2`
[1] "Llo"

$`3`
[1] "emo"
```

To avoid confusion, here's the same code without the variable named split:

```
number_of_words <- 2
lapply(split(el(strsplit(string,'')),1:number_of_words),paste0,collapse='')
$`1`
[1] "Hello"

$`2`
[1] "Lemon"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
paste0(split[seq(1,nchar(string),by = 2)],collapse="")
[1] "Hello"
> paste0(split[seq(2,nchar(string),by = 2)],collapse="")
[1] "Lemon"
```

It appends even and odd positions in the string `string`

Answer (score 1):

Another way using your `split` variable, will work with any number of words:

```
N <- 2
apply(matrix(split,N),1,paste,collapse="")
# [1] "Hello" "Lemon"
```